# Why did Marx write Das Kapital altough he believed revolution doesn't come by reading books?

Tags: economy, political-economy

[https://www.unm.edu/~soc101/quotemarx.htm](https://www.unm.edu/%7Esoc101/quotemarx.htm)

> The mode of production in material life determines the general character of the social, political, and spiritual processes of life. It is not the consciousness of men that determines their existence, but on the contrary their social existence determines their consciousness.

> The philosophers have hitherto only interpreted the world in various ways. The point, however, is to change it.

So if Marx thought that it is pointless to change the ideas people have in their mind (for example explaining capitalism to them), why did he write Das Kapital? In it he explains of course how capitalism works. But only knowing it, doesn't change a thing, according to him

Answer (score 2):

Technically, *The Capital* was supposed to be a "scientific" study of the existing economic and social relations - not a propaganda tool to drive a revolution. Indeed, for many decades Marx was outshined by more charismatic and energetic personalities, notably by Ferdinand Lassalle - the creator of the first german workers party. (Lassalle died a year after creating the party, but, to great annoyance of Marx and Engels, remained a prominent figure for german social democrats for more than half a century afterwards - his portraits were displayed alongside those of Marx in the party conferences, and revisionist current initiated by Eduard Bernstein was essentially reversion to Lassallean ideas. Notably, Lassalle believes in victory of socialism by peaceful democratic means, rather than through a violent revolution.)

Later in life Marx and Engels came to conclusion that a spontaneous rising of the workers could never win against more organized and better armed liberal bourgeoisie. Hence there emerged the idea of workers being educated, organized and led by a *revolutionary vanguard*/*communist party*, composed of intellectuals such as Marx and collaborators . Although these ideas are usually attributed to Lenin, who developed and popularized them, they were originated by Marx.

Answer (score 1):

For Marx there was [a reciprocal relationship between the material base and its ideological superstructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_and_superstructure).

The first quote emphasizes that the material base was *primary*, but it does not exclude any influence in the reverse direction. The second quote directly implies that the point of philosophy is to change the world, which supports this latter possibility.

Marx wrote *Capital* as a critique of the ideology of capitalist political economy. He did not think that this critique itself would change the material relations of capitalism. But by dispelling the ideology of capitalism he hoped to empower the workers movement to make material changes.